# Fórmula para calcular intervalos numéricos no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou a precisar de uma ajuda para fazer uma fórmula em Excel.

```
=SE(C11<=6;"G4";SE(6<C11<=10;"G6";SE(10<C11<=16;"G10")))
```

O que quero fazer é:

Se a célula `C11` for menor ou igual a 6 escrever `G4`.
Se a célula `C11` for maior do que 6 e menor ou igual a 10 escrever `G6`.
Se a célula `C11` for maior do que 10 e menor ou igual 16 escrever `G8`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você precisa usar `SE` aninhados

```
=SE(C11<=6;"G4";SE(C11<=10;"G6";SE(C11<=16;"G8";"FALSO")))
```

Neste caso ele vai testar as condições uma de cada vez, quando for menor ou igual a 6 retorna verdadeiro para o primeiro `SE` e escreve `G4`.
Quando for maior 6, testa o segundo `SE`, se for menor ou igual 10 retorna verdadeiro e escreve `G6`.
Quando for maior do que 10, testa o terceiro `SE`, se for menor ou igual a 16 escreve `G8`.
Senão escreve `FALSO`;

**[Função SE](http://office.microsoft.com/pt-br/excel-help/se-funcao-se-HA102752994.aspx)**

Comment: Olá, boa tarde! Fiz a função e deu certo, porém minha faixa de intervalos contém números decimais, por ex: 25.5, 26.8 etc, e o Excel não identificou os valores decimais.

Comment: Olá @SaraFernandes o Excel reconhece vírgulas para separar as casas decimais, você tentou utilizando vígulas, exemplo: 25,5; 26,8 e etc...

Comment: Olá @abfurlan, meu arquivo é  do tipo CSV e meu delimitador é "vírgula" por esse motivo utilizo "ponto" para separar casas decimais.

Answer (score 0):

Ou assim para evitar muitos "SE":

```
=se(C11<=6;G4;se(e(C11>6;C11<=10);G6;se(e(C11>10;C11<=16);G8;se(C11>16;"Valor foi maior que 16")
```

Comment: Na sua resposta tem um "SE" a mais do que na pergunta e na outra resposta. Por que você diz que assim "evita" muitos "SE"?