# Fórmula para retornar a data apenas com dias úteis

Tags: microsoft-excel, planilha

Existe alguma fórmula que eu possa utilizar para a célula retornar a data correspondente ao prazo?

Se insiro a data 03/01/2020 na célula, queria que outra célula ao lado retornasse a data com o cálculo de 5 dias úteis.

Seria assim:
03/01/2020

A célula ao lado retornaria 10/01/2020 automaticamente considerando apenas dias úteis.

Posto que já tipifiquei as células como data, uma simples soma resolveria o caso. Supondo que o valor de A1 é 03/01/2020

```
=A1+5
```

Ele me retorna 08/01/2020 quando na verdade deveria ser 10/01/2020. O problema é que ele não considera apenas os dias úteis.

Comment: Posta o código que você já tentou fazer,e você já deu uma olhada nisso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23537/f%c3%b3rmula-para-calcular-intervalos-num%c3%a9ricos-no-excel?rq=1 ?

Comment: Não entendi como a fórmula `SE` poderia ajudar neste caso. Mesmo se aplicasse condições, não retornaria a data.

Comment: Então poste a parte do código que você esta com problemas

Comment: Pronto, Kalibban, inseri minha tentativa fracassada.

Comment: De fato ele ira te retornar 08/01/2020 pelo fato de você estar fazendo uma soma.

Comment: Exatamente, eu queria saber se há alguma forma de configurar a contagem apenas com os dias úteis, mas não deve existir, eu acho.

Comment: A função DIATRABALHO faz exatamente isso. https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/diatrabalho-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-diatrabalho-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33

Comment: @anonimo a função DIATRABALHO precisa ser passado as 2 datas como parâmetro,e pelo que eu entendi ele vai dar a entrada numa data qualquer e informar 5 dias,para que a partir dai ocorra o retorno da data contabilizando 5 dias uteis.

Comment: @KALIBBAN: creio que você confundiu a função DIATRABALHOTOTAL com a função DIATRABALHO.

Comment: @anonimo realmente eu confundi,mas mesmo assim ambas precisam ter 2 datas como parâmetro,e o que ele esta tentando fazer e passar uma data e uma quantidade de dias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheguei a solução atraves da função

> DIATRABALHO.INTL

Você passa os parâmetros para a função e ela te trara a data corretamente

```
=TEXTO(DIATRABALHO.INTL(DATA(2020;1;3);5;1);"dd/m/aaaa")
```

Utilizei a data 03/01/2020 como base de parâmetro e ele me retornou a data 10/01/2020

Usei essa fonte de pesquisa https://www.tudoexcel.com.br/planilhas/funcao-diatrabalho-intl-do-excel-3784.html

Comment: Se: `A1 = 03/01/2020`, `A2 = 5` e em C1 tenho o feriado 20/01/2020, a fórmula: `=DIATRABALHO(A1;A2;C1)` dará como resultado: `10/01/2010`.
Se: `A1 = 16/01/2020`, `A2 = 5` e em C1 tenho o feriado 20/01/2020, a fórmula: `=DIATRABALHO(A1;A2;C1)` dará como resultado: `24/01/2010`.
Considerando os fins de semana como sendo sábados e domingos não há necessidade de utilizar a função `DIATRABALHO.INTL`.

Comment: @anonimo dessa forma você obriga a pessoa a informar uma data para feriado em C1,isso tambem e possivel com a função `DIATRABALHO.INTL`,onde ele so precisa informar a data inicial e tendo a opção de calcular feriados ou fins de semana,então eu acho válido utiliza-la.